# When creating a HTML extension like BeginForm, can I grab the content as a string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to find a way to capture the inner content supplied to a Html Extension within a 'using' block (similar to Html.BeginForm). I've read about using a an IDisposable class for rendering the end block - this is what I have so far:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    private class RZScript : IDisposable
    {
        private HtmlHelper _helper;
        private string _outputContent;

        public RZScript(HtmlHelper helper)
        {
            _helper = helper;
            _outputContent = new HtmlTextWriter(_helper.ViewContext.Writer).InnerWriter.ToString();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _helper.ViewContext.Writer.Write("(AAAA)" + _outputContent + "(CCCC)");
        }
    }

    public static IDisposable TestThis(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        return new RZScript(htmlHelper);
    }
}
```

I'm then testing this tag with:

```
<p>test</p>
@using (Html.TestThis())
{
    @:(BBBB)
}
```

The result I'm hoping to get is:

> test (AAAA)(BBBB)(CCCC)

What I actually get is:

> test (BBBB) (AAAA) test (CCCC)

Any idea how (or if!) I can get the content into a string? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got something working. Not the syntax I was after but the outcome is the same.

```
public static IHtmlString RegisterScriptInline(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    Func<object, IHtmlString> content)
{
    string renderedContent = content.Invoke(null).ToString(); // Got it!!!
    return null;
}
```

And then this would be called with something like (extended example to show server-side conditions in Razor do evaluate):

```
@Html.RegisterScriptInline(@<text>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        @if (someCondition)
        {
            @:var item = 'Value1';
        }
        else
        {
            @:var item = 'Value2';
        }
    </script>
</text>)
```

There's no starting/ending content here - however, all the AAAAs and CCCCs etc in my question were there as delimiters just to show I was trying to extract the BBBBs(!) I won't mark this as the answer for the moment as it gives me the result I wanted but it doesn't specifically answer the question.

(Reproducing @section sort of functionality if you're wondering...)